# Vim YouCompleteMe Java setup

Tags: java, vim, youcompleteme

I'm trying to set up Java autocompletion for Vim using the YouCompleteMe plugin. I ran the install script and got the following message saying that I need to set an option called `java_binary_path`:

```
$ python3 install.py --java-completer --clang-completer
Generating ycmd build configuration...OK
Compiling ycmd target: ycm_core...OK
Building regex module...OK
Building watchdog module...OK
Installing jdt.ls for Java support...

*** WARNING ***: jdt.ls requires Java 17. You must set the option java_binary_path to point to a working java 17.


OK
```

I tried setting this in my `~/.vimrc` file as follows, but now I'm getting the error `E518: Unknown option: java_binary_path=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/bin/java`:

```
set java_binary_path=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/bin/java
```

Does anyone know how to set this option?

Comment: Add `/usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/bin` to your `$PATH`. Executing `java -version` in your terminal should output the correct version.

Comment: @AlexR Thanks, that worked. But I wonder if the java_binary_path option allows you to achieve this without setting your system Java binary to 17.

Comment: I don't think so as there seems to be no such option as you check for yourself [here](https://github.com/ycm-core/ycmd/blob/master/build.py#L1038) and [here](https://github.com/ycm-core/ycmd/blob/master/CheckJavaVersion.java).